# Using the google drive api, how do I check if a user can share a file publicly with or without link?

Tags: google-drive-api

See: [Is it possible to share a file publicly through Google Drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665215/is-it-possible-to-share-a-file-publicly-through-google-drive-api)

Using the information above, If I attempt to set the necessary permission for a specific file, I receive the following:

> Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{somefileid} permissions: (403) Insufficient permissions for this file

This error only occurs for google accounts tied to a google apps for edu setup where the admin has unchecked the option Google Apps -> Settings for Drive -> Share Settings -> Outside this organization: "Allow users to publish files on the web or make them visible to the world as public or unlisted files"

Using the Permission feed works fine otherwise, but ideally I would like to know if there is a way to check for this setting beforehand, instead of catching the 403 exception from the drive service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`About.get()`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get) endpoint to get details about the user's Drive, including this sharing setting. The field `domainSharingPolicy` can have the values `allowed`, `allowedWithWarning`, `incomingOnly` and `disallowed`. The first two in that list should allow publishing outside the domain, while the second two should not.